# Partially ordered set of graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

As a homework assignment I am to find minimal, maximal, biggest, and smallest elements of a partially ordered set $M$.

Let $G$ be an arbitrary connected graph on $n$ vertices.

> $M$ is as a set of ALL subgraphs of $G$, with $n$ vertices and no cycles.
>
> The ordering of a set $M$ is defined as two graphs $A,B \in M$ are related
>
> $A \leq B$ if $A$ is a subgraph of $B$.

What I have got so far:

- minimal and also smallest element is a graph with $n$ vertices and no edges, i.e. an empty graph;
- maximal would be all the spanning trees of a graph $G$. If there only is a single spanning tree, then that tree is also the biggest element of $M$.

Is my reasoning correct? Is an empty graph on $x$ vertices a subgraph of any connected graph on $x$ vertices?

Comment: In some context minimal can mean smallest not lease element and maximal largest not biggest element.  Maximal ideals are an example.

Comment: Why wouldn't the minimal elements be graphs witn one vertex and no edges? (Unless by "ALL subgrphs" you mean "all SPANNING subgraphs"?) "There is only a single spanning tree" could be put more simply as "the graph is a tree".

Comment: @bof they need to have n vertices,   And to the "ALL spanning subgraphs" graphs in M need not be connected, and a spanning tree needs to be connected.

Comment: A "spanning subgraph" of a graph $G$ is a subgraph of $G$ (not necessarily connected) which contains all the vertices of $G.$ A spanning subgraph which also happens to be a tree is a spanning tree, and needs to be connected. "All subgraphs" certainly includes subgraphs with fewer than $n$ vertices. You meant to say that $M$ is the set of all spanning subgraphs of $M.$ And yes, the empty graph on a vertex set $V$ is a (spanning) subgraph of **every** graph on $V,$ connected or not.